# Jmeter:how to get a weekday from _RandomDate()

Tags: jmeter, weekday

I'm using the jmeter __Randomdate() to generate a date and pass it to an API request. most of the time, the date generated are weekends.how to get only the weekdays?

I'm trying to use the __timeshift() if it is weekend, but the __time(EEE,) is giving the day for a current date not from a variable. Can someone help with this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of JMeter's built-in test elements is not suitable for your requirement, you will need to go for i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and calculate the date there using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

Example code would be something like:

```
static def randomWeekdayDate(Date start, Date end) {
    def random = new Random()
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(start)

    def daysBetween = (long) ((end.time - start.time) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    def randomDays

    while (true) {
        randomDays = random.nextInt((int) daysBetween + 1)
        cal.setTime(start)
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, randomDays)

        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        if (dayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY && dayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY) {
            break
        }
    }

    return cal.time
}

def start = new GregorianCalendar(2024, Calendar.JANUARY, 1).getTime()
def end = new GregorianCalendar(2024, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31).getTime()

def randomWeekday = randomWeekdayDate(start, end)

vars.put('randomDate', randomWeekday as String)
```

You will be able to refer generated value as `${randomDate}` where required